# How to save high frame rate camera images without losing image

Tags: c++, multithreading, camera, queue

i have an Gige Camera and i want to make a code to get received images showing them in openCV window and saving them with JPEG compression on disk at high frame rate around 70-75 FPS but i can't do it in the same thread because image processing is to low to keep pace, so i tried a storage worker to queue and saved image but i move my problem for 1 image saved i got 3 or 4 new image queue and RAM is increasing too much, it's ok for 1 or 2 min running but i need to run for at least an hour.

Comment: Let's forget for now showing them in a window (or at least let's allow to skip frames). How much time does it take on your machine to acquire and save 1 frame? How many threads can you run in parallel and how much time does it take to save n frames in parallel under different filenames? Try to measure it to check if your task is doable on your hardware.

Comment: Easiest solution: get faster hardware and more RAM.

Comment: In a similar situation, I found I had to use 2 storage devices, 2 threads, and 2 queues in addition to the queue used to receive data. If you want to display images, you'll probably need yet another thread and queue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.